# How to call my concrete class method when I keep calling the base class method

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

Given these classes :

```
public abstract class Car
{
    public void Copy(Car car)
    {
        // stuff //
    }
}

public class Ford : Car
{
    public void Copy(Ford updatedFord) 
    {
        base.Copy(updatedFord);
        // copy ford stuff //
    }
}

public class Holden  : Car
{
    public void Copy(Holden updatedHolden) { .. }
}
```

and this is what I'm trying to do...

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    Car car1 = new Ford { Colour = "Red", StickerCount = 1 };
    Car car2 = new Ford { Colour = "Blue", StickerCount = 666 };

    car1.Copy(car2);
    // I expect blue AND 666 to be copied. only Blue is.
}
```

[Here's all the code in a .NET FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qC7j0L).

So in this scenario, if the car is a `Ford` instance, then the `Copy(..)` method on the `Ford` class, is called .. not the copy method on the `Car` instance.

I'm just not sure how to make the Copy method get called on the most concrete class (and then `base.XXX()` calls through the inherited hierarchy.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sf3srI

Comment: Make `virtual` `Copy` method of `AggreagateRoot` and override it from inherited classes. Fiddle => https://dotnetfiddle.net/NYKAyv

Comment: @MitatKoyuncu now you're casting in every 'level'. eg. `Colour = ((Car)car).Colour;` *urgh*

Comment: In your case you have static binding i.e. compile time because your methods are non-virtual. Why do you declare the instances as `Car` when you sure they are `Ford`?

Comment: As per your design, Holden car can be copied to Ford car. Is this correct design?!

Comment: Nope. can't copy a holden to a ford.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `Ford.Copy` is not declared on the base class, and therefore is not accessible after you cast your `Ford` to a `Car`.

`Ford.Copy` needs to override `Car.Copy`.

But since its parameter has a different type, it can't just override the base method.

What you need is to parameterize `Car` - `Car<TCar>` - and then use that type parameter to define your parameter type. Each subclass will then specify what type of car they'll be copying.

This is called [F-bound polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification).

```
public abstract class Car<TCar> where TCar : Car<TCar>
{
    public virtual void Copy(TCar car)
    {
        // stuff //
    }
}


public class Ford : Car<Ford>
{
    public override void Copy(Ford updatedFord) {}
}

public class Holden  : Car<Holden>
{
    public override void Copy(Holden updatedHolden) { .. }
}
```

Comment: Where do you see hiding(shadowing) the base class member?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Ah you're right, it's not hiding it, it's an overload. Which is not accessible from the base class. I'll amend this detail.

Comment: Is there way to avoid putting generics on the `class` but on the single method, instead?

Comment: @Pure.Krome Unfortunately, no :/ If the method was generic, then a `Ford` would have to handle copying *any* car. You wouldn't be able to restrict `Ford.Copy` to ford cars only.

Comment: I find `T : Car<T>` to be redundant, but can't think of a better way. +1

Comment: @ArthurRey Without `T : Car<T>`, then you could have a `class Ford : Car<Banana>` :/ thanks!

Comment: @dcastro Sorry to bother you again. Can you please edit your answer with the abstract `Car` -class- inheriting from an `abstract class AggregateRoot` class (which has the Copy(..) method in it) please? (My .NET fiddle has an example of this, in it) *beg*

Comment: And finally @dcastro how would I cast .. say .. a `Ford` to an `AggregateRoot`? eg. `var root = myFord as AggregateRoot;`

Comment: @Pure.Krome You'd have to cast it to a `AggregateRoot<Ford>`. Looks ugly, I know :/ The problem is that your `Copy` method depends on the concrete instance being copied, and this affects your `AggregateRoot`.

Comment: And the other problem I have now is that I can never just pass an `Car` around anymore. I now need to pass a `Car<SomeConcreteClass>` which  ... sorta defeats the entire purpose here :( I don't care about the parent classes ... just the abstract class. hmmm.

Comment: @Pure.Krome Yup, you can't treat all cars the same, because a car can only copy another car if they're of the same type. That is, you wouldn't know what car you could pass to `car.Copy(???)`. Just like you can't do `pet.AddChild(puppie)`, because `pet` could be a cat, and cats can't have puppies.

Comment: Which leads me to think the whole design needs to be re-thought. Maybe separate the copying responsibility from the car? What's this copy method supposed to do? Make `this` car look like some other car?

Comment: -exactly- my thoughts now. I think I need to design the `Copy` a bit different. Thanks kindly! (you definitely did help/lead me to the answer).

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the behavior you want:

```
    dynamic car1 = (Car)new Ford { Id = 1, Colour = "Red", StickerCount = 1 };
    dynamic car2 = (Car)new Ford { Id = 2, Colour = "Blue", StickerCount = 666 };
```

Comment: Polluting your codebase with dynamically compiled code to solve such a simple problem will cause mayhem.

Comment: Forget dynamics for this purpose. Have you ever seen what kind of code will be compiled when using dynamics? Not mentioning the terrible performance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "hidding" here. He is overloading `Car.Copy(Car)`.
This should help you find your self.

```
using System;

class A
{
    public void Foo(A a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A.Foo");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    //overloading
    public void Foo(B b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Overload");
    }

    //hiding
    public new void Foo(A a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hide");
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A(); 
        A b = new B();
        B c = new B();

        a.Foo(a);   //A.foo

        b.Foo(a);   //A.foo
        b.Foo(b);   //A.foo
        ((dynamic) b).Foo(a); //hide (equivalent to overriding Foo in B when A.Foo is virtual or abstract)

        c.Foo(a);   //hide
        c.Foo(b);   //hide
        c.Foo(c);   //overload
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Copy method should be a virtual one.

```
public abstract class Car
{
    public string Colour { get; set; }

    public virtual void Copy(Car car)
    {
        Colour = car.Colour;
    }
}

public class Ford : Car
{
    public int StickerCount { get; set; }

    public override void Copy(Car car) 
    {
        base.Copy(car);
        Ford ford = car as Ford;
        if (ford != null)
            StickerCount = ford.StickerCount;    
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    Car car1 = new Ford { Colour = "Red", StickerCount = 1 };
    Car car2 = new Ford { Colour = "Blue", StickerCount = 666 };

    // if Copy is not virtual, Car.Copy will be called here instead of Ford.Copy!
    car1.Copy(car2);

    Console.WriteLine("Result should be blue: " + car1.Colour);
    Console.WriteLine("Result should be 666: " + ((Ford)car1).StickerCount);
}
```

Comment: What if `car` is not a `Ford`? Do you throw an exception? You're giving up on static checking.

Comment: It depends on the design. The generic solution makes possible to copy from the same types only, which can be intended. This solution copies the possible properties from any car type, which also can be an intended design.

Comment: Err... any reason for downvoting?

Answer (score -2):

You have to declare Car.Copy as virtual and Ford.Copy with overide. Then it should work.